# NameError: name 'screen' is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter

I keep getting an error saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\name\Desktop\dice\login system.py", line 64, in <module>
    loginForm()
  File "C:\Users\name\Desktop\dice\login system.py", line 33, in loginForm
    screen1 = Toplevel(screen)
NameError: name 'screen' is not defined
```

This is for a school project and I first have to make a login system, this is everything that could have to do with the error:

```
def main_screen():
    global screen
    global USERNAME
    global PASSWORD
    screen = Tk()
    screen.title('Name')
    screen.geometry("340x200")
        
    USERNAME = StringVar()
    PASSWORD = StringVar()

    Label(text = 'Welcome to Name', bg = 'grey', width = 300, height = 2, font = ('calibri', 12, 'bold')).pack()
    Label(text = '').pack()
    Button(text = 'Login', height = 2, width = 30, command = loginForm).pack()
    Label(text = '').pack()
    Button(text = 'Register', height = 2, width = 30, command = registerForm).pack()

    screen.mainloop()
def Database():
    global conn, cursor
    conn = sqlite.connect("db_member.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `member` (mem_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTINCREMENT NOT NULL, username TEXT, password TEXT)")

 def loginForm():
    global screen1, lbl_result1
    
    screen1 = Toplevel(screen)
    screen1.title('Login')
    screen1.geometry("400x400")

    lbl_title = Label(screen1, text = "Login", bg = 'grey', width = 50, height = 2, font = ('calibri', 12, 'bold'))
    lbl_title.pack()
    lbl_username = Label(screen1, text = "Username:", font = ('calibri', 25, 'bold'), bd = 18)
    lbl_username.pack()
    username = Entry(screen1, font = ('calibri', 20, 'bold'), textvariable = USERNAME, width = 15)
    username.pack()
    lbl_password = Label(screen1, text = "Password:", font = ('calibri', 25, 'bold'), bd = 18)
    lbl_password.pack()
    password = Entry(screen1, font = ('calibri', 20, 'bold'), textvariable = PASSWORD, width = 15, show = "*")
    password.pack()
    lbl_result1 = Label(screen1, text = "", font = ('calibri', 18, 'bold'))
    lbl_result1.pack()
    btn_login = Button(screen1, text = 'Login', font = ('calibri', 18), width = 25, command = login)
    btn_login.pack()

def login():
    Databse()
    if USERNAME.get() == "" or PASSWORD.get() == "":
        lbl_result1.config(text = 'Please complete all the fields', fg = 'orange')
    else:
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `member` WHERE `username` = ? and `password` = ?", (USERNAME.get(), PASSWORD.get()))
        if cursor.fetchone() is not None:
            lbl_result1.config(text = 'You logged in successfully', fg = 'blue')
        else:
            lbl_result1.config(text = 'Invalid Username or Password', fg = 'red')
loginForm()

main_screen()
```

Since I have done  `def login():` it keeps saying that either screen is not defined or that USERNAME and PASSWORD are not defined.

Comment: `USERNAME.gett` should be `USERNAME.get()`

Comment: @Atlas435 thanks I changed it <3

Answer (score 3):

`global screen` does not define a variable; it simply says that the name refers to a global variable named `screen` *if it exists*.

The problem is that you are calling `loginForm` (which tries to get the value of `screen`) before `main_screen` (which actually assigns a value to the name `screen`) is called.

You should not, however, be using so many global variables. Pass values as arguments to functions, use return values, and consider using classes to encapsulate data that can't be comfortably be shared via argument passing.

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing the variable `screen` as global variable in `main_screen` and you are using it in `loginForm` but you call `loginForm` before `main_screen` and `screen` wasn't initialized.

Answer (score 0):

It is because screen is in fucntion and other function can't see it you need to put it outised of function or give it argument self.